# Font size change in iterm2 does not change the font size of my tab title. How can I do this?

Tags: iterm2

I am trying to change the font size of my iterm tab title. However, changing the default font size does not seem to work. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe it's not possible at all to change tabs font size